# How can i find the rate of change of water in a cube tank?

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, related-rates

In a cube shaped water tank of volume $8m^3$, water is poured into it at the rate of
$0.4 \,m^3/h$. Find the rate of change of increase water level with respect to time.

The following is the solution I obtained. I don't know if it's right or not; please let me know if it is correct or not and feel free to offer tips.

- water volume

$$V = x^2h \tag 1$$

- tank volume

$$V = x^3 , V = 8 \implies x = 2 \,m \tag 2$$

by equation $(2)$ in equation $(1)$

$$V = 4h$$

$$\frac {dv}{dt} = 4\frac {dh}{dt}$$

$$0.4 = 4\frac {dh}{dt}\implies \frac {dh}{dt} = 0.1 \,m/h$$

Comment: You should show what you have tried, your work and effort.

Comment: ok, sorry i'm new to this community

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: The numbers are correct. But you have a mixture of numbers with unit and numbers without unit. Either make a statement at the beginning, saying that all lengths are in meters and all times are in hours (derived units accordingly), and then skip the units in your calculation and only put them back again in the answer, or put the units on all intermediate results.

Comment: @S.alhaider Yes your solution is fine, just add some unity as indicated for clarity.

Comment: To go along with what @ReinhardMeier said, be sure to not mix up upper and lower case letters. For example you have $V=4h$, then you have $\frac{dv}{dt} = 4\frac{dh}{dt}$. Are you implying that $\frac{d}{dt}V = \frac{dv}{dt}$? $V$ could indicate volume, while $v$ could indicate velocity. Do you see what I mean?